# flexNav.js submenus are off centered

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am want to use the [Flex Navigation](http://jasonweaver.name/lab/flexiblenavigation/)
plugin to create a responsive menu.

The plugin works, but when I add submenus, they are not correctly centered underneath their parent.

[Heres a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5m7r5848/1/)

It doesn't completely work in the fiddle, and I'm not sure why, but you can still see the offcentered submenu that I'm talking about.

Here is a screen shot to illustrate what I'm seeing.

[image: Screenshot]

Here is my HTML

```
    <div class="small-12 large-8 columns navHolder">
        <div class="menu-button">Menu</div>
        <ul class="flexnav with-js opacity sm-screen flexnav-show" data-breakpoint="1025">
            <li class="navOption"><a href="#">Nav 1</a></li>
            <li class="navOption"><a href="#">Nav 2</a></li>
            <li class="navOption"><a href="#">Nav 3</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="nav-list"><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
                <li class="nav-list"><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="navOption"><a href="#">Nav 4</a></li>
        </ul>            
    </div>
```

I didnt change any of the plug in CSS but here is the custom stuff I have in my own style sheet

```
/*Header*/
#mainLogo{
    margin-top:20px;
}

.loginSignUpButtons p{
    margin-top:20px;
}


/*FlexNav*/
.navHolder{
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/5m7r5848/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The submenus have padding, remove that:

```
.navOption ul {padding:0}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2d0q03t3/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't declare a value for Padding then most web browsers will add Padding to your UL elements by default, setting `padding:0` on your UL should correct your issue.

Use a good CSS reset to prevent these kind of problems in the future: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5m7r5848/4/